# “Impacte” ou “impacto”?

Tags: significado, etimologia, uso-de-palavras, diferenças, origem

Ao procurar a diferença entre as palavras `impacte` e `impacto`, deparei-me com os seguintes pontos:

> Os significados de **impacto** apresentados nos nossos dicionários
> coincidem com os significados que lemos no dicionário inglês de
> **impact**.
>
> A forma **impacte** é apenas, pelo menos parece, o inglês **impact** "transplantado" para português e adaptado a ele, mas escusadamente.
>
> [Fonte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/impacte-para-que/385)

e

> nos usos não especializados e mesmo em certos contextos mais ligados
> ao debate político, como é o caso de «**impacte**/**impacto** ambiental», não
> é possível afirmar que as duas formas sejam mais do que variantes
> livres da mesma palavra.
>
> [Fonte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/novamente-impacto-e-impacte/29059)

Nesse sentido e, pelo que percebi, não parece haver diferença entre ambos os termos (embora **impacte** pareça ser mais utilizado num âmbito especializado, como «**impacte** ambiental» ). E, se existe, ela

> encontra-se no plano etimológico: impacte aparece em português por empréstimo da forma que o latim *impactu-* tomou em inglês, impact, enquanto impacto tem relação directa com o latim (cf. [Dicionário de Língua Portuguesa](http://www.infopedia.pt/pesquisa) da [Porto Editora](https://www.portoeditora.pt/) - DLPPE).
>
> [Fonte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/novamente-impacto-e-impacte/29059)

Por forma a clarificar este ponto, existe diferença entre ambos os termos? Se sim, qual?

Se não, como me parece, porquê admitir ambas as formas?

Comment: Interessante, jamais tinha visto "impacte" como substantivo, eu diria que deve ser muito pouco usada em pt-BR.

Comment: Assim como @stafusa, nunca vi “impacte” como substantivo na minha vida. Gostaria de adicionar que uma das tuas fontes responde a uma pergunta tua de diferença (ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/…), dando quatro acepções e em “Em suma, o contraste entre as duas formas não parece semântico”. Este diz que a diferença não parece ser semântica, ou seja, não parece houver diferença de significado. Outra fonte o fortalecendo é que todos os dicionários que vi também põem “impacte” como variante de “impacto”.

Comment: Concordo com @stafusa.

Comment: Acho ridiculo "impacte" quando existe impacto que é a tradução correta de impact em inglês. Quando não existe algo tudo bem, mas quando existe, credo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), restringe ***impacte*** a Portugal, e o que parece ter acontecido é que em Portugal houve um tempo em que se considerou que ***impacto*** era só adjetivo, sendo o substantivo *impacte*. Atualmente, de acordo com todos os dicionários, à parte de *impacte* não ser adjetivo, como substantivo é o mesmo que *impacto*.

### O adjetivo *impacto*

O adjetivo apareceu primeiro. Já vem no dicionário do [Raphael Bluteau de 1713](https://books.google.pt/books?id=48ZKAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA3-PA64&lpg=RA3-PA64&dq=%22IMPACTO%20Termo%20de%20Medico%22&source=bl&ots=aLznUKtQdk&sig=ACfU3U1JPAJ-sgWrxJ8ILrtamZr2mbXhw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8qYWW-tz2AhUIJBoKHZ6qB8AQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22IMPACTO%20Termo%20de%20Medico%22&f=false):

> IMPACTO. (Termo de Medico.) Metido fixamente dentro […] Podridão *impacta* na substancia & entranhas.

Este *impacto* vem do latim [*impactus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impactus) particípio passado de *impingere*, e corresponde aos adjetivos francês *impacté* (já em 1561 neste [*Traité des Hernies*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Mr9EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA409&dq=%22impact%C3%A9%20en%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiezeTaod72AhVfQ_EDHV9CDqUQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22impact%C3%A9%20en%22&f=false)) e inglês *impacted* (a partir de 1680; ver [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impacted#etymonline_v_51295)).

Este é ainda o único significado de *impacto* no dicionário de [Domingos Vieira de 1873](https://books.google.pt/books?id=B5paAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1033&dq=%22Impacto%20a%20adj%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzvO-i_Nz2AhXIS_EDHUOpAwE4HhDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Impacto%20a%20adj%22&f=false) e no de [Moraes Silva de 1891](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bs44AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA156&dq=%22Impacto%20a%20adj%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzvO-i_Nz2AhXIS_EDHUOpAwE4HhDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Impacto%20a%20adj%22&f=false).

Creio que este uso seja raro hoje em dia. Eu não conhecia; eu dira *encravado* ou coisa assim, em vez de *impacto*. Também no inglês, o [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impacted#etymonline_v_51295) diz que o sentido original de *impacted* é preservado em [*impacted tooth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_impaction) (depreendo eu que seja raro noutros contextos). Também nós temos *dente impacto* (’que ficou encravado dentro da gengiva’), como “dentes impactos ou de difícil erupção” [(Revista Brasileira de Odontologia, 1945)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=IkZQUnr4EmEC&q=%22dentes%20impactos%22&dq=%22dentes%20impactos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsyYW65OD2AhUMhP0HHQqTCQI4ChDoAXoECAIQAg); parece ser ainda comum hoje em dia.

### O substantivo *impacte / impacto*

O Houaiss atesta *impacte* em 1922, 3ª edição do dicionário de Cândido Figueiredo. Eu não tenho essa edição, mas tenho a 6ª, de 1939, em que *impacto* continua a ser só adjetivo:

> **Impacte** *m*. O mesmo que *impacção*. Acto de (uma bola *ou* outro projéctil) bater *ou* tocar no alvo; ponto de encontro com o mesmo alvo. (De *impactar*).
> **Impacto**, *adj.* Impelido, metido à força. (Lat. *impactus*).

O dicionário de 1962 de Pedro Machado (Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa, Lisboa) mantém a mesma distinção. O da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001) já diz que *impacte* é sinónimo de *impacto* e que vem do francês. Encontra-se *l’impacte* no francês no século XIX (não procurei depois), mas a forma dominante e oficial é *impact*, já desde 1824 (ver [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/impact)); em inglês, o substantivo *impact* está atestado em 1738 ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=impact)).

No Brasil parece nunca se ter usado *impacte*, e mesmo em Portugal, apesar do que disseram os dicionários de meados do século XX, já antes se encontrava o substantivo *impacto*. O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei é “pontos de impacto dos tiros” nesta [*Collecção Official de Legislação Portugueza* de 1864](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dowvAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA122&dq=%22impacto%20dos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQy6Slpd72AhVD6RoKHQKtAcEQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22impacto%20dos%22&f=false). O próximo é já de 1937, “impacto da prosa” no [*A Criação do Mundo* de Miguel Torga](https://books.google.pt/books?id=U5juAAAAMAAJ&q=%22impacto%20da%22&dq=%22impacto%20da%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCxqufuN72AhWMfMAKHe69DGk4PBDoAXoECAEQAg).

Mas exemplos de *impacte* anteriores a 1950 também não encontrei muitos. O mais antigo é de 1907, novamente “ponto de impacte” (de tiros) na [*Collecção Official de Legislação Portuguesa*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CaUvAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ponto%20de%20impacte%22&dq=%22ponto%20de%20impacte%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiggo2N5972AhVBSvEDHReiCYkQ6AF6BAgFEAI). De maneira que não sei se isso de *impacto* ser só adjetivo correspondeu ao uso dominante em Portugal ou se foi mania do Cândido de Figueiredo e eventualmente dalguns outros linguistas.

No Brasil, encontrei o substantivo *impacto* a partir de 1889 ― “a pressão fluidica é o resultado medio do impacto das moleculas”― na [*Revista do Observatorio* do Rio de Janeiro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Wr5BAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22impacto%20das%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_rrS-ut72AhXags4BHbZiDjEQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22impacto%20das%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

Nunca tinha visto a palavra "impacte". Consultando um dicionário da Porto Editora, surge como sinónimo de "impacto". Considerando o verbo "impactar"- fazer embater contra, "impacte" é a conjugação da 3ª pessoa do singular do imperativo

Answer (score 0):

A palavra "[impacto](https://dicionario.priberam.org/impacto)" corresponde a uma adaptação semântica da palavra do latim "impactus" que surge do facto de no português nomes masculinos terminarem normalmente com a letra "o" (veja por exemplo o caso da palavra "[controlo](https://www.infopedia.pt/$controlo-ou-controle)" que é um empréstimo do francês "contrôle"). Já a palavra "[impacte](https://dicionario.priberam.org/impacte)" é uma adaptação semântica da palavra do inglês "[impact](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/impact)", que não respeita a regra dos géneros (possivelmente por na altura não se conhecer ou não se ter definido o seu género), mas sim a regra associada ao facto das palavras em português terminarem com uma vogal após a letra "t", por razões de fonética. Esta adaptação é assim menos rigorosa que a primeira (a primeira respeita ambas as regras). Note-se também que a transição da sílaba "ct" para "cte" é menos abrupta do que "ct" para "cto" já que a primeira não altera o a fonética (quando as sílabas são proferidas nas respetivas línguas) para além da grafia. Este tipo de adaptação é semelhante àquele que se tem no caso de palavras que resultam de empréstimos de palavras do francês que não alteram a fonética, como por exemplo, "camionete", "controle", "avionete", "trotinete", etc. Estas palavras são também usadas e têm o mesmo significado que aquelas que resultam da adaptação que respeita a regra dos géneros: "camioneta", "controlo", "avioneta", "trotineta", etc. Seguindo o mesmo princípio, "impacte" e "impacto" devem de ter o mesmo significado, e podem ser usadas quer no sentido de "ação com contacto", quer no sentido de "efeito forte em algo" (tal como o  dicionário [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/impacto) menciona).

O facto da palavra "impacte" ser bastante utilizada em conceitos da área das Ciências deve-se provavelmente a uma maior habituação a esta palavra por parte da estirpe de pessoas que transmitem conhecimentos na área que à palavra "impacto". Os conhecimentos passam de pessoa para pessoa recorrendo à mesma palavra, independemente do uso de outras fora da área.

Portanto, como resposta à questão "**existe diferença entre ambos os termos?**" devo responder não para a maior parte das pessoas, mas sim para algumas (por mera habituação). Quanto à questão "**porquê admitir ambas as formas?**", devo dizer que como ambas se usam com frequência significativa, não faz sentido suprimir uma ou outra, já que a língua tende a evoluir naturalmente por habituação (uso e desuso das palavras), a não ser que acordos ortográficos (que são por vezes pouco naturais) sejam impostos.